# Paginator selection number of rows not showing correctly

Tags: angular, html-table, material-ui

I have a table like this one in angular material
[image]

Can someone tell me why 'Items per page' numbers are shows under the table and not under select option element (orange marker)?

This is my html template.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">          
        <div>
            <h3>MyTable</h3>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%">
                    <!-- Index Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> x </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">{{ (i+1) + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize)}}</td>
                    </ng-container>
        
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="x1">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> x1 </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.x1}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
        
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="x2">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> x2</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.x2}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
        
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
        
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row 
                        *matRowDef="let reading; columns: displayedColumns;"
                        (click) = "onRowClicked(reading)"
                    ></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        
            <mat-paginator #paginator
                [length]="countX"
                [pageSize]="pageSize"
                [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                aria-label="Choose page"
                showFirstLastButtons>
            </mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u have  "styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", added in your angular json?

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. How come this was not there by default dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @D A said in comments:
I had to add css in angular.json

> Do you have "styles":["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
> added in your angular json?